# Retrieving RESTful GET parameters in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to get logstash to parse key-value pairs in an HTTP get request from my ELB log files.

the request field looks like
`http://aaa.bbb/get?a=1&b=2`

I'd like there to be a field for `a` and `b` in the log line above, and I am having trouble figuring it out.

My logstash conf (formatted for clarity) is below which does not load any additional key fields. I assume that I need to split off the address portion of the URI, but have not figured that out.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/ubuntu/logs/**/*.log"
        type => "elb"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "log_sincedb"
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "elb" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} 
%{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int}
%{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int} 
%{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float}
%{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} 
%{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} 
%{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int}
%{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int} 
%{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} 
%{QS:request}" ]
        }
        date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
        }
        kv {
            field_split => "&?"
            source => "request"
            exclude_keys => ["callback"]
        }
    }
}


output {
    elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

Comment: Does the grok{} filter make a `request` field?  What's in it?

Comment: Yes, the very last piece of the grok field is `%{QS:request}`. It's a URL as specified in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv) will take a URL and split out the params. This config works:

```
input {
    stdin { }
}

filter {
    mutate {
            add_field => { "request" => "http://aaa.bbb/get?a=1&b=2" }
    }

    kv {
            field_split => "&?"
            source => "request"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

stdout shows:

```
{
   "request" => "http://aaa.bbb/get?a=1&b=2",
         "a" => "1",
         "b" => "2"
}
```

That said, I would encourage you to create your own versions of the default URI patterns so that they set fields.  You can then pass the querystring field off to kv. It's cleaner that way.

UPDATE:

For "make your own patterns", I meant to take the existing ones and modify them as needed.  In logstash 1.4, installing them was as easy as putting them in a new file the 'patterns' directory; I don't know about patterns for >1.4 yet.

```
MY_URIPATHPARAM %{URIPATH}(?:%{URIPARAM:myuriparams})?
MY_URI %{URIPROTO}://(?:%{USER}(?::[^@]*)?@)?(?:%{URIHOST})?(?:%{MY_URIPATHPARAM})?
```

Then you could use MY_URI in your grok{} pattern and it would create a field called myuriparams that you could feed to kv{}.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "create your own versions of the default URI patterns", what function/filter should I be looking at?

Comment: Also, there was an unrelated reason why I did not see the values correctly. Kibana was looking at the wrong index. {facepalm}.