# Parse url parameters in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm sending data in a url to logstash 5.2 and I would like to parse it in logstash, so every url parameter becomes a variable in logstash and I can visualize it properly in kibana.

```
http://127.0.0.1:31311/?id=ID-XXXXXXXX&uid=1-37zbcuvs-izotbvbe&ev=pageload&ed=&v=1&dl=http://127.0.0.1/openpixel/&rl=&ts=1488314512294&de=windows-1252&sr=1600x900&vp=1600x303&cd=24&dt=&bn=Chrome%2056&md=false&ua=Mozilla/5.0%20(Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_11_3)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/56.0.2924.87%20Safari/537.36&utm_source=&utm_medium=&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_campaign=
```

This is my logstash conf file:

```
input 
{
  http 
  {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 31311
  }
}

output
{
    elasticsearch
    {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }

    stdout
    {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) filter to match your params in your url as such:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{URIPARAM:url}" ]
  }
```

And then you might have to use [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv) filter in order to split your data:

```
kv {
    source => "url"
    field_split => "&"
  }
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863494/retrieving-restful-get-parameters-in-logstash) might become handy. Hope this helps!